# Adding nuget packages for a webapi project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I am trying to change the default location of `nuget` packages

I have a  `nuget.config` file in the `same location as the solution file`.

Its contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="Lib" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

But the problem is still when I go to `Manage Nuget Packages` and click `Restore`, the libraries go to `packages` folder but not to `lib` folder.

This only happens to the `WebAPI` project file but not to any other projects in the same solution.

Any ideas why ?

Should any thing be changed to the `web.config` files ?

Comment: Try removing the 'packages' directory, then from Package Manager Console do 'Update-Package -reinstall'.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after placing the `nuget.config` file, close and re-open the visual studio (restart it).

It will now read the `nuget.config` file and then will understand that it needs to download all the packages to the configured folder in the `nuget.config` file.